# Azure Data Factory U-SQL activity dynamic parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

Lets suppose I have a U-SQL script which get executed every one hour from ADF pipeline.
I have mssql database which contains config table. Is there any way to read a  config from database and pass it to U-SQL script? 
In [ADF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-usql-activity) i couldn't find any way of doing it. Only SliceStart, SliceEnd, but what if my parameter is type of GUID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in ADF V2 (currently in Public Preview) using the Lookup activity.  The lookup activity can pass the lookup results to the subsequent activity (in your case U-SQL activity).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity

Comment: can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138273/pass-multiple-dynamic-parameters-to-u-sql-script-via-data-factory