# pass multiple dynamic parameters to U-SQL script via data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

currently I can pass one parameter to u-sql script in data factory workflow.
and with that parameter i can apply some pattern to generate files paths.
is there any way to pass collection of datetimes parameters to u-sql and 
apply pattern to generate file paths?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple parameters. U-SQL also allows parameters of type `SqlArray<>`. I am not sure though if ADF supports passing in such typed values. I think the PowerShell APIs do allow it.

I assume that passing the values as a file will not work, since you will not get compile time partition elimination with it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a Json parameter. Then handle it with u-sql.